# moving a process to fg and bg

Tags: shell, process, session

Suppose I run a process in the background likw `./script &`, I can bring it to foreground by running fg.

However, is there a way to move it back to background without stopping it (as in `ctrl+z`) or opening a new session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. I usually do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and `%1&` or `bg 1` where '1' is the job number.

If you have a separate terminal and know the process id, you can do `kill -20 500; kill -18 500` (if your process id is 500) to first suspend and then start in background.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is not possible. You can however do the following

```
[usr@localhost:~]$ sleep 100 &
[1] 28542
[usr@localhost:~]$ fg
sleep 100
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 100
[usr@localhost:~]$ bg
[1]+ sleep 100 &
[usr@localhost:~]$ jobs -l
[1]+ 28542 Running                 sleep 100 &
```

Another alternative is to use `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: problem with screen is that I need to decide before hand. This was the rare occasion where the bring back is unplanned :)